# MS Access Unicode Characters in Where Clause Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, unicode

I have a ms access database that contains unicode characters - specifically Chinese characters. When searching for data in the db as shown below nothing is returned:

```
Select * From 测试 Where 测试 = '测试';
```

This problem is fixed in sql server by prefacing the search string with N:

```
Where 测试 = N'测试'
```

However I am unsure how to resolve the problem in ms access.

It is able to deal with the characters when they are column headers i.e. in the From but any comparision in the Where clause fails.

Comment: Have you tried using: Where 测试 LIKE '测试*'

Comment: In what context are you trying to run this query? I just created a test table and pasted your query into the Query Designer in Access 2010 and it worked properly. (The table had three rows, one of which contained `测试` and the query returned just that row.)

Comment: I am running this query in Access 2010 but it is linked to a sql server database. Would there be any settings that could cause this to fail?

Comment: And Where 测试 LIKE '测试*' also returns no values

Comment: I was able to recreate the issue in Access 2010 with a linked table to SQL Server 2008 R2. The `测试` row shows up in Datasheet View but it does not show up in the WHERE query, and it also does not show up if I select that value in Datasheet View and choose `Filter Selection Equals "测试"`. Very strange.

Comment: Thank you Gord for trying out and confirming the issue - could you please advise on what I can do to get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try using FIRST instead of WHERE. Are you trying to query text from a memo field, and grouping? you may want to look at the post from Allen Browne about this issue:
http://allenbrowne.com/bug-18.html

Comment: I'm not sure how you would use FIRST in this case? And no I'm not trying to query text from a memo field/grouping. Just a simple search query as shown above.